# XCode compile time error on simultor

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to build my XCode project and this is what I get. The project runs fine on a device but fails to run on simulator.

[image: Build Error]

Can someone please explain me why this is happening. I have tried removing this library from the project and add it again. It still fails to run on simulator.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i386 is a reference to the Intel processor architecture used by your development machine (the actual iOS devices use ARM processors).

The error indicates that the library has not been built to include support for the Intel architecture. As the simulator runs on the desktop, it requires Intel support to run.

You should obtain a copy of the library that includes i386, or build it yourself.

Here's one way that can be done (for another library that required i386 support adding)

http://www.federicocappelli.net/2012/10/05/zbar-library-for-iphone-5-armv7s/

Comment: CkoCrypt2 is part of a library. That library has two files. They both are named same though. one is for Device and other for Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find where CkoCrypt2 is defined in code and make sure it's being built for the simulator.

If "CkoCrypt" is part of a library or framework, then you need to also compile that library to work under a simulator as well.

Comment: CkoCrypt2 is part of a library. That library has two files. They both are named same though. one is for Device and other for Simulator.

Comment: Assuming they are both .a files for the respective architectures, they can be merged using a variation of the instructions I linked to to create one lib that supports both. Something like, lipo -create Release-iphoneos/libckocrypt.a Release-iphonesimulator/libckocrypt.a -o libckocrypt.a