# XCode 4.5, Static Libraries, and Categories

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to use a static library, and the categories that are in it aren't being used at run-time.  There are no compile-time errors, but when I go to run, I get the standard 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' message and my app crashes.

Many solutions say to add `-ObjC -all_load` to the "Other Linker Flags" property in your application's target (many others say that as of XCode 4, that is no longer needed, this is the only reason I have bothered to include the XCode version).  I've tried it and I get 115 errors during build:

`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CLLocationCoordinate2DMake", referenced from:
      -[QMapElement init] in libQuickDialog.a(QMapElement.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKMapView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libQuickDialog.a(QMapViewController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKPinAnnotationView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libQuickDialog.a(QMapViewController.o)
  "std::istream::gcount() const", referenced from:
      GT::AES::decode(std::istream&, std::ostream&, unsigned int&, bool) in GD(gtaes.o)
      GT::AES::encode(std::istream&, std::ostream&, unsigned int&, bool) in GD(gtaes.o)
  "std::string::find_first_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      -[GDSetPasswordViewController checkPasswordStrength:] in GD(GDSetPasswordViewController.o)
      GD::EacpCReq::EacpCReq(std::string, std::string, GT::Dbb&) in GD(GDEacpCommands.o)
      GD::RawSocket::connect() in GD(GDRawSocket.o)
  "std::string::copy(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      GD::Socket::toString() const in GD(GDSocket.o)`

(and so on, that's about 5 or 6 of the 115).

Whether I have either of those linker flags, or both, I get the exact same set of errors.

Not sure if this is the culprit, or just coincidental, but after looking at the errors a little more closely, it seems like they are all from one of two 3rd-party libraries I am using.  One as an installed .framework, the other as a regular static library. Maybe I need to do something to their builds (if possible), as well?
Thanks!

Comment: See this thread for a similar problem, which may help...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090156/xcode-compile-time-error-on-simultor/13090196#comment17839707_13090196

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the error message is pointing to a few missing frameworks:

1. CoreLocation (`_CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` symbol);
2. MapKit (`_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKPinAnnotationView` symbol);
3. C++ standard library.

Try to include them with your target... specifically, for the C++ standard library, you should check a specific build setting in Xcode under "Apple LLVM Compiler x.y - Language".

This will not rule out the chance of other missing frameworks, of course...

Comment: That got me started, actually, down to 112. Now to just figure out which other frameworks those things are in. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Yep, just needed one of the three libstdc++ libraries.  Each got me to 0 errors, just need to figure out from my 3rd-party framework provider if it matters which one I use.  Thanks again!